# Best way to parse and concatenate a string with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to turn `object_type,ABC,00,DEF,XY` string into `ABC-00-DEF-XY-`

Here's what I've got, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way?

```
CONCAT(
     REPLACE(
        SUBSTR(a.object_name, 
               INSTR(a.object_name, ',',1,1)+1, 
               INSTR(a.object_name, ',',1,2)+1
              ),',','-'
            ),'-'
      )
```

Clarification: I need to strip off everything up to and including the first comma, replace all remaining commas with dashes, and then add a dash onto the end.

Comment: possibly regex replace - hard to tell your full requirement here

Comment: clarified in first post i hope

Comment: your approach is efficient enough, the best thing you can do here is make your instr/substr/replace code shorter. regexp may look neat but it performs way worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
replace(substr(a.object_name,instr(a.object_name,',',1,1) + 1),',','-') ||'-'
```

Answer (score 1):

[Rexexp_replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions115.htm#sthref1608) regular expression function can come in handy in this situation as well:

```
select ltrim(
             regexp_replace( col
                           , '([^,]+)|,([^,]+)', '\2-'
                            )
             , '-'
             ) as res
 from t1
```

Result:

```
RES
--------------
ABC-00-DEF-XY-
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/06521/1)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the following code:

```
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(a.object_name,13,LEN(@object_name)-11),',','-') + '-'
```

Comment: The -11 won't work in this case because another example of input could be `ABCD-PAD12-EFGH-XZZ`, the field that make up those segments theoretically could be up to 32 alphanumeric chars each (although we are only using 2-5 now)

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested because it works for me regardless of how long your input could be e.g. object_type,ABCD,PAD12,EFGH,XZZ will return ABCD-PAD12-EFGH-XZZ-

Comment: I get many errors on: @, SUBSTRING, LEN, +. I changed it to this to get it to run, but the -11 causes problems because the first part of the string can be variable too. assume all components are variable. `REPLACE(SUBSTR(a.object_name,13,LENGTH(a.object_name)-11),',','-') || '-'`